# Best way to store a list in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I currently have a ContentProvider that fetches a list of resources from a remote server. The data is stored in an SQLite database.

From this list, users would be able to add several items to their favorites. Their app would then have to keep track of the IDs from the list. What is the best way to keep track of the list of favorites?

I thought of a few...

1. Have a flag in the SQLite table to mark if it has been favorited.
2. Serialize the list of IDs and store using Shared Preferences
3. Store it using another SQLite database

Answer (score 4):

This depends.

I would recommend **variant 1**, because it will keep your data structure simple and you just add one more flag. (This will require you to alter the table if it is already live?)

I have done the same in an application i've created too, and it works very fast. You also have the information if it was starred in the same model so it won't require any additional logic if you need this information to display it inside a detail-view

---

Variant 2 is a really bad idea and it will be really slow. (slow in comparison to the sqlite solutions)

---

Variant 3. You don't require another SQLite database. You will have to add a new model which refers to the main data model. But this only makes sense if you have a 1:n relation

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion first one having a flag in SQlite table to mark a row as favourite is the best options. With this approach you read the data once from db and you know which ones are marked favourite.

Answer (score 1):

You say you need to keep track of a list of favourates? I'm assuming this means you want to use a list of favourates on a fairly regular basis.

Instead having to traverse the entire table each time you wish to read the list of favourates, it makes sense to me to make another table containing all the IDs marked as favourate. You can read this table frequently with little cost.

The IDs in this table will serve as a foreign key to link to the main table.

Comment: I like this idea, but how does that work with regard to ContentProviders? I would need some way to "join" the tables together -- which is my main issue.

Comment: You'd need to create a separate "DBHelper" class which will handle all the DB stuff. With this, execute a SQL JOIN query to...well..join tables together.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first thought is the best, as you are not have to match the data a second time.